# How to duplicate Unix sort semantics in Pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, linux, pyspark

My implementation of a procedure uses the Unix/Linux sort utility, first sorting the whole file, then sorting only unique elements (-u) option.

I want to do this in Pyspark, but I don't see how. I tried `intersect`, `subtract` and `select distinct`. (`select distinct` gets only the fields involved in the sort, but I need an ID field as well.)

What is a Pyspark-only solution?

Comment: Can you add an example of input/output? Is your input still a file or something else?

Comment: Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Just ask a (single clear specific researched non-duplicate on-topic) question. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Yes-or-no questions are poor & typically not actually asking for what is wanted. Ask what you want the answer for. PS Emphatic typography is seldom needed. Clarity comes from writing clearly. Please read the edit "?" help & "advanced help" re formatting & don't abuse formatting, use it for what it is intended for. PS Strunk & White: "Omit needless words."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can do the trick?

```py
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, SparkSession


def unix_sort(spark, input_filepath, out_filepath):
    """Read a file, unix-sort it and save to another file"""
    file_content_df = spark.read.text(input_filepath)
    sorted_content_df = (
        file_content_df
        .dropDuplicates()
        .orderBy(F.col('value').asc())
    )

    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    print(temp_dir)

    # Write to output file
    # 1. save in a temporary folder
    sorted_content_df.coalesce(1).write.format("text").option("header", "false").mode("append").save(temp_dir)

    # 2. Find the file in the temporary folder
    temporary_file = next(filter(
        lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.txt',
        next(os.walk(temp_dir))[2]
    ))
    
    # 3. Move the file in the final destination path
    shutil.move(os.path.join(temp_dir, temporary_file), out_filepath)
    
    # 4. Remove the temporary folder
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

Suppose that the input file `input_file.txt` is:

```bash
1haao
AAAA
BBB
alpha
Beta
Gamma
delta epsilon
theta
2iota
```

running the following code:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
unix_sort(spark, "input_file.txt", "out_file.txt")
```

a file called `out_file.txt` will be created with the following content:

```bash
1haao
2iota
AAAA
BBB
Beta
Gamma
alpha
delta epsilon
theta
```